# Regex select text and nearest wrapper

Tags: regex

I have this text

```
<div>another words</div>
<div>
  some text here
</div>
```

I want to get `<div>` element which contains 'text' word. result's here:

```
<div>
  some text here
</div>
```

I can do it like this:

```
<div>.*text.*<\/div>
```

but it selects all text.

Comment: What's the context? Regex can be a pretty bad choice of tool to parse HTML if the scope isn't where limited.

Comment: @Robin i have very dirty html, without closed tag etc.

Comment: Then regex are definitely not your answer. What language are you using? In most HtML parser this would be both easier and a lot safer to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div>[^<]*text[^<]*<\/div>
```

To not include tags in the inner part of the match.

Also, regexp is not an ideal tool for parsing html. - Consider if your use case is better served by "proper" html parsing tools.

Edit:
If you have nested tags you are definitly leaving the area where regexp is a suitable tool.  However you might be able to use negative lookahead;

```
<div>(.(?<!<div>))*text(.(?<!<div>))*<\/div>
```

This will misbehave if you need to handle nested div's.  And probably in other edge cases, use at own risk.

Comment: thanks, it works, but what can i do if div element contains another tags? [b] or [strong]

Comment: @Wachburn Use tools dedicated to HTML parsing.

Comment: @Wachburn Answer edited for a possibility if you insist on poking sleeping old ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = <<< EOF
<div>another words</div>
<div>
  some text here
</div>
EOF;

preg_match('%<div>s+(.*?text.*?)\s+</div>%s', $html, $result);
$result = $result[1];
echo $result;
//some text here
```

http://ideone.com/qwFlJ8